# Cannot connect to imap server on python

Tags: python, imap

I'm a networking student who has little programming experience and I have simple project on my hands where I need to make a simple notification that notifies the user when an email arrives in gmail. I have been trying to get this to work for the last few weeks and I am honestly stuck and struggling. I'm using the code below and I think the problem is the authentication bit, where I can't connect to the server. All help is appreciated.

```
import imaplib
import re
import time
import subprocess

## enter your account details bellow!
imapServer = "imap.gmail.com"
port = "993"
username = "example@gmail.com"
password = "password"

##how often to check ? give interval in seconds! Checking too often might performance and stability.
checkInterval = 120

Mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imapServer, port)
rc,resp = Mailbox.login(username,password)
if rc == 'OK':
    print("Connected to mail-server " + imapServer)
rc, message = Mailbox.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
unreadCount = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)",str( message[0])).group(1))
oldValue = 0
file = open("%sytemdrive%\Windows\Temp\mailnotify.tmp", "w+")
file.write(str(unreadCount))
file.close
while(1):
    rc, message = Mailbox.status('INBOX', "(UNSEEN)")
unreadCount = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)",str( message[0])).group(1))
file = open("%sytemdrive%\Windows\Temp\mailnotify.tmp", "w+")
oldValue = int(file.readline())
file.close()
if (unreadCount>oldValue):
    subprocess.call(["notify-send", "-u", "low", "low", "t", "5000", "New email!", "New email!",
                     "You have " + str(unreadCount) + " unread " + "emails!" if unreadCount > 1 else "email!",
                     "--icon=email"])
    if oldValue != unreadCount:
        file = open("%sytemdrive%\Windows\Temp\mailnotify.tmp", "w+")
    file.write(str(unreadCount))
    file.close()
    time.sleep(checkInterval)
else :
    print('Fail to connect')
    Mailbox.logout()
    file.remove()
```

Comment: What I would try is adding an `else` clause to the check of the result of `Mailbox.login`: if `rc` is not `OK`, print out `resp`. That should give you a clue about what's going wrong.

Comment: For gmail specifically, you need to enable Less Secure Apps in the settings.  The modern world doesn't like basic authentication.